# how to improve performance of nested for loops when comparing values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++){
      if(nums[i] + nums[j] === target){
        return [nums.indexOf(nums[i]), nums.lastIndexOf(nums[j])]
      }
    }
  }
}
function([3,5,3,7,2], 9) //It should return [3, 4] since 7 + 2 = 9
```

This is a Javascript function and it's iterating over the array of numbers with nested for loops and find a pair that when summed, it equals the target and return their indexes. Since it has a nested for loop it I believe it has O(n^2) or quadratic time complexity, and I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this. I'm just trying to get the first pass solution and after improve upon it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use arrays, but an appropriate lookup data structure.

Comment: @Bergi The tricky thing is that the array allows duplicates, most lookup structures don't.

Comment: It doesn't help your complexity problem, but you shouldn't need to call indexOf since i and j are already indexes

Comment: Sort the array, then you can use binary search to find `target - nums[i]`.

Comment: @Barmar But in this situation we don't care about duplicates, do we?

Comment: @Bergi If the target is `6` it should return `0` and `2`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, so make a lookup structure from value to highest index. We don't need to care about multiple indices.

Comment: I see. Yes, just check that the index isn't the same as `i`, so it's a different element.

Comment: If you sorted the array, and your target was *M* then you can walk in from one end while stepping back on the other and look for matches more algorithmically. Like test 0 and n-1, then 0 and n-2, etc. There's a limited number of potential matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an object that maps each element to its last index. Then loop over each element, and see if `target - element` is in the object with a different index.

```js
function twoSums(nums, target) {
  const last_index = {};
  nums.forEach((num, i) => last_index[num] = i);
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    const diff = target - nums[i];
    if (diff in last_index && last_index[diff] != i) {
      return [i, last_index[diff]];
    }
  }
}

const list = [3,5,3,7,2];
console.log(twoSums(list, 9));
console.log(twoSums(list, 6));
console.log(twoSums(list, 15));
```

Looking up an object property is O(1), so this algorithm is O(n).

Comment: the complexity is still O(n*n)

Comment: No, it's O(n). Property lookup is O(1).

Comment: Oh, yes that's correct, but what if there's only one 3 and you needed to get the sum of 6? You might need to store the frequency as well?

Comment: The question is about finding pairs of elements. His code never reuses the same element, they're always different.

Comment: If there is a duplicate value, wouldn't "map[num] = i" override the previous index?

Comment: Yes, that's intentional. The map contains the last index of each number.

Comment: `i` will be the first index. That's why I check that they're not equal, it prevents using the same element twice.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You could use nested `map()`:

```js
var twoSum = (nums, target)=> {
  //  map trough list for first number
  nums.map(
   (val1, index1)=>
    {
      // map through list again for second number to compare to number returned from first map at each instance
      nums.map((val2, index2) =>
      {
      //  Ensure that index1 and index2 are not the same before you compare
        if(index1 != index2 && (val1 + val2 === target))
        {
          alert([index1, index2]);
          return [index1, index2];
        }
      });
    }
  );
}

twoSum([3,5,3,7,2], 9) //It should return [3, 4] since 7 + 2 = 9
```

Note: Remember this won't loop through all the items unless a match has not been found. As soon as a match is found, the function returns, and exit.

Comment: This is also O(n^2). You also don't prevent using the same element twice, and don't stop when the solution is found.

Comment: __return__ exits the function when the solutions is found, remember that @Barmar.

Comment: You're only returning from the function being mapped, not exiting the loop.

Comment: There's no way to break out of a `map()` loop.

Comment: That was a mistake.

Comment: Notice that you get two alerts, for `3, 4` and `4, 3`.

Comment: Also, if you're not using the result, you should use `forEach` rather than `map`.

Comment: Makes Sense @Barmar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sLpb2g58/  Just to be a contrarian, you can break out of a map.

Comment: Yes, by throwing an error is the only way @Taplar, I thought about adding it. But, Somehow I felt like maybe I shouldn't hah aha..